# how to fetch record associated with all values in IN() Operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch record associated with all values in array. but the problem is, query is fetching record if any one values in IN() is present in db . i  want to fetch record ONLY if all values are true.

```
SELECT J.ID , J.U_POST_ID,
       J.TITLE,J.CREATION_DATE,J.STATUS,
       R.FIRST_NAME, R.LAST_NAME,R.CLINICAL_CLINIC_NAME,
       J.REQUIREMENT,J.STATE,J.CITY,J.DESCRIPTION,
       J.CALL_DUR,J.USER_ID
FROM  df_job_meta M 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN df_job_post J ON M.JOB_ID = J.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN df_register_users R ON R.ID = J.USER_ID
WHERE
    J.STATUS='ACTIVE' AND 
    R.OCCUPATION !='student' AND 
    J.STATE IN ('Maharashtra') AND 
    J.CITY IN ('Nagpur') and  
    M.VALUE IN ('Clinical','Fresher','BDS Intern','Full Time')
```

table df_job_meta

```
---------------------------------------------
***VALUE***       |  **META_KEY**  |  JOB_ID 
--------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
Part Time         | work_hour      | 103
-------------------------------
BDS Intern        |qualification   | 103
----------------------------------------
Clinical          |profile         | 103
----------------------------------------
1                 |num_vacancy     | 103 
----------------------------------------
1 to 3 Years      |experience      | 103

--------------------------------------
```

Comment: If you want all values to be true you have to use `AND`, not `IN`. `IN` is an extended OR condition.

Comment: Also why use an `IN` clause when there is only one item in the IN list. Use `=`

Comment: I don't understand the question. Instead of the IN clause you'd have `M.VALUE = 'Clinical' AND M.VALUE = 'Fresher'` and so on? Doesn't make sense in my head.

Comment: and cannot be use multiple time for same column

Comment: all  values i an getting in array format that's why in  no. of values can be more or less every time

Comment: Please explain how `m.value` from a single row can contain all of the values `'Clinical','Fresher','BDS Intern','Full Time'`

Comment: have a look at table i have drawn below query with table name  df_job_meta  .where VALUE,META_KEY,JOB_ID  are column name

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to generate some Dynamic SQL. For the set of coded values you gave:

```
SELECT J.ID , J.U_POST_ID,
   J.TITLE,J.CREATION_DATE,J.STATUS,
   R.FIRST_NAME, R.LAST_NAME,R.CLINICAL_CLINIC_NAME,
   J.REQUIREMENT,J.STATE,J.CITY,J.DESCRIPTION,
   J.CALL_DUR,J.USER_ID
FROM (
    SELECT M1.ID
    FROM df_job_meta M1
       INNER JOIN df_job_meta M2 ON M1.JOB_ID = M2.JOB_ID
       INNER JOIN df_job_meta M3 ON M1.JOB_ID = M3.JOB_ID
       INNER JOIN df_job_meta M4 ON M1.JOB_ID = M4.JOB_ID
    WHERE M1.VALUE = 'Clinical'
        AND M2.VALUE = 'Fresher'
        AND M3.VALUE = 'BDS Intern'
        AND M4.VALUE = 'Full Time'
) as JOBS_MATCHING_META
    LEFT OUTER JOIN df_job_post J ON M.JOB_ID = J.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN df_register_users R ON R.ID = J.USER_ID
WHERE
    J.STATUS='ACTIVE' AND 
    R.OCCUPATION !='student' AND 
    J.STATE IN ('Maharashtra') AND 
    J.CITY IN ('Nagpur')
;
```

(untested)

I would note that looking at your sample data for `df_job_meta` whether you need to be looking at the `META_KEY` column too - ie the value is only valid if it's for the right thing, for example

```
WHERE M1.META_KEY = 'qualification' AND M1.VALUE = 'BDS Intern'
```

As a final observation, it looks like yuo are trying to implement some form of facetted search; perhaps it might be worth looking at some alternative data stores that implement that directly?